# Finding the least double greater than in Java

Tags: java, floating-point

Is there a built-in method to find the next greatest double number in Java?

When writing a test, I sometimes want to verify that an operation succeeds for `x` but fails for values greater than `x`. One way to do this is to show that the operations fails for `x + eps`. But `eps` must be chosen taking into account the value of `x` to avoid problems like `180 + 1e-15 == 180`.

To automatically select `eps`, I'd like to find the smallest representable number greater than `x`. I was surprised that I didn't find a standard library method, so I wrote the following:

```
public static double nextDouble(double d) {
    if (d < 0) {
        return -prevDouble(Math.abs(d));
    } else {
        return Double.longBitsToDouble(Double.doubleToLongBits(d) + 1);
    }
}

public static double prevDouble(double d) {
    if (d < 0) {
        return -nextDouble(-d);
    } else {
        return Double.longBitsToDouble(Double.doubleToLongBits(d) - 1);
    }
}
```

Should I use these custom functions, or is there a built-in approach available?

Comment: Note that with this "find the smallest representable number greater than `x`", code will have infinity when `x` is the maximum finite value and code will not be symmetric for `-x`.  Consider instead finding the [ULP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place) for your `eps`.

Comment: @chux: Why? Infinity is the next representable number greater than the greatest finite representable number.  If you want, as the problem states, to test an operation for values greater than x, and x is the greatest finite representable number, then you should test it at infinity. Finding the ULP of x will not serve any purpose.

Comment: @EricPostpischil ULP I find less problematic & more symmetric to report than the next greater for epsilon testing. True that a working `nextDouble()` will satisfy OP's question though may not meet a higher level goal.  My comment included potential surprising issues about `nextDouble()` (infinity and asymmetry) and proposed an alternative consideration. As with such code, the edges case at the various powers-of-2 deserve attention as ULP there has various definitions.   [Example](http://ljk.imag.fr/membres/Carine.Lucas/TPScilab/JMMuller/ulp-toms.pdf), which I am sure of which you are familiar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is [the `Math.nextUp` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#nextUp-double-).

> Returns the floating-point value adjacent to d in the direction of positive infinity.

There are overloads to take `double` and `float`.  There are also corresponding `Math.nextDown` methods.

Comment: This is perfect, thanks. Interesting that `Math.nextUp` was added in Java 6 but `Math.nextDown` didn't arrive until Java 8.